# d3 - draw lines n number of times

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a vertical-line which is drawn using `d3`. Suppose I want to repeat the line for a several number of times like a bar code. How do I do it?

I know that it has to be done using `for` but i don't have any clue on how to do it.

Suggestions will be very much helpful.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NS7WF/)

Here's the code:

```
var height = 500;
    var width = 500;

    var svgContianer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)


    var line = svgContianer.append("line")
                            .attr("x1", 20)
                            .attr("x2", 20)
                            .attr("y1", 100)
                            .attr("y2", 0)
                            .attr("stroke", "#000")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better options than using a `for` loop. But, in any case [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/NS7WF/2/)

```
var height = 500;
var width = 500;
var count = 10, padding = 5;
var svgContianer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)

for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var line = svgContianer.append("line")
                            .attr("x1", padding*i)
                            .attr("x2", padding*i)
                            .attr("y1", 100)
                            .attr("y2", 0)
                            .attr("stroke", "#000")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
}
```

Comment: I need one more help. Can you help me out?

Comment: Please check this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465096/d3-mouseover-and-mouseout-event-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a bar code, the D3 way to do it would be to bind each line (element) with its width (data) and then using D3's `enter` phase to construct them.

Also, for bar-codes, you would also want to turn `shape-rendering` to `crispEdges`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pGB4z/).

```js
var height = 500;
var width = 500;

var svgContianer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)


var line = svgContianer.selectAll("line")
    .data([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2])
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function (d, i) {
      return 20 + 5 * i;
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
      return 20 + 5 * i;
    })
    .attr("y1", 100)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {
      return d;
    })
```

Comment: Actually it's not a barcode. Kinda like a barcode. Anyways you're answer was also useful for me. +1 vote. I need one more help. Can you help me out?