# d3 - mouseover and mouseout event not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a series of line that's created using d3. And i've written some `mouseover` and `mouseout` event events.

When I `mouseover` the event works properly by increasing the `y1` value of the line.

But on `mouseout` the event doesn't works properly where i've written code set back the `y1` value to the initial value.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NS7WF/3/)

Help me to fix this.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/NS7WF/4/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. That's the thing i was looking for. What was the mistake I did over there? And please post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with d3 transitions you need to be careful when nesting transitions or executing them simultaneously.

[The solution](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/NS7WF/4/)

I just changed the `moveout` method to update the `stroke` and `y1` of all lines irrespective of which line triggered the function. And, the `movein` method to reset the `y1` of all lines before extending the currently rolled-over line.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for that. +1 vote. And when the `mouseout` happens. It's appearing instantly. Can't we add a transition over there?

Comment: Any documentation i can get on this `d3.node()`?

Comment: No! `d3.select(target).node()` is missing from the documentation. It essentially gives you the element itself and not the encapsulated object with d3 properties & methods.

Comment: How can we make the `mouseout` color transition to get smoothed. It's appearing instantly the moment `mouse` is moved out.

Comment: Please help me with this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLrsQ/). Move your mouse right to left and vice versa fastly and notice the error. Please help.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/eLrsQ/1/) out and compare with your fiddle. You were not resetting `y2`.

Comment: Keep moving the mouse from left to right and vice versa. Few bars will be in half white color. Make the mouse to stay on it and the bar will will expand in the same half white color. But it's supposed to be in grey.

Comment: Just updated the stroke of the current line in `movein` function. [**Updated function**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/eLrsQ/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That did really help me. I do require more and more help on d3. Looking for your support when required.

Comment: Can i get your personal mail id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42772/discussion-between-srvikram13-and-user2549787)